# Difference between 'по-настоящему' and 'как следует'

Tags: значения

If I am not mistaken, 'по-настоящему' and 'как следует' generally mean 'properly' or 'in the right way.' Is there a difference in usage and meaning between these words?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, *Как следует* may be not just an idiom for "*properly*", but also a construction similar to either "*as it follows from*" or "*as it ought to*".

On the other hand, *По-настоящему* literally means "*for real*", "*really*". So these words are not always interchangeable.

> Подумай *как следует* --> do *proper* thinking; think twice
>
> Подумай *по-настоящему* --> do *real* thinking (mostly unmeaningful)

Answer (score 4):

"**По-настоящему**" typically means doing something **at full strength**, without simplification or imitation of some action for some reason, for example:

```
боксировать по-настоящему,  без скидок на неопытность соперника
```

"**Как следует**" (*the way it should be done*) means doing something *properly or thoroughly*, **as** one is **supposed to do** it. The expression is usually opposed to someone's possible revealing their laziness or is based on a precedent of not doing their best. "**По-настоящему**" can be used in similar meaning without a hint at a person's imperfection (it's a bit 'politically correct').

```
На этот раз вымой пол как следует.

(more friendly) Вымой сегодня пол, только по-настоящему (= как ты это умеешь).
```